# how to make up a 2D feature following a Gaussian distribution, given the mean and standard deviation?

Tags: python, plot, normal-distribution

I'm stack in trying to plot a two-dimensional feature which has a mean of [2, 3] and standard deviation [0.4, 1.5], along the x and y axis, respectively.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.random.normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) to generate N samples from a gaussian distribution, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np

xs = np.random.normal(loc=2, scale=0.4, size=100)
ys = np.random.normal(loc=3, scale=1.5, size=100)
```

As you might have guessed, `loc` corresponds to the mean, and `scale` to the standard deviation.